# Hide next button on last item jCarousel

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I am using jCarousel. I want to hide next or previous button when user reach to last or first element. I used wrap 'circular' and wrap 'circular' but none of them work for me. Here is code which I write for the initializing the carousel. I there any pre defined option available for purpose or I have to add my own function for this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6w2j9oqf/2/).

```
 $(".slider").jcarousel({
        auto: 1,
        wrap: "last"            
        }).jcarouselAutoscroll({
            interval: 1000,
            target: '+=1',
            autostart: false
        });

     $(".jcarousel-control-prev").on("jcarouselcontrol:active", function() {
            $(this).removeClass("inactive")
        }).on("jcarouselcontrol:inactive", function() {
            $(this).addClass("inactive")
        }).jcarouselControl({
            target: "-=1"
        });
        $(".jcarousel-control-next").on("jcarouselcontrol:active", function() {
            $(this).removeClass("inactive")
        }).on("jcarouselcontrol:inactive", function() {
            $(this).addClass("inactive")
        }).jcarouselControl({
            target: "+=1"
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

By removing wrap option from jCarousel. Its works fine for me

```
$(".slider").jcarousel(                 
        ).jcarouselAutoscroll({
            interval: 1000,
            target: '+=1',
            autostart: false
 });
```